# Are the rules to the board game Quintet known?

Tags: quintet

In the 1979 film [Quintet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079770), a board game of that name is played, and it has also been taken to "the next step", roll playing for life and death by the rules of the board game. But what exactly are those rules? Is the script for the film publicly available, and if so, does it explain the rules more explicitly than the film does? Or are there any other resources, perhaps some statement about it from one of the writers? Even fan made rules would be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, it seems the rules are actually available [here](https://ghostradio.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/robert-altmans-quintet-learn-the-rules/). In this link, the download-able pdf seems to be from the **original movie pamphlet**. I am attaching the screen-shot of rules page for your reference.

[image]

P.s. Please try **NOT** to play in real life :)

Comment: Beautiful. What was your exact search term? I've googled it a few times, but either my google ability is impaired, or I missed this one although it was there for me to see.

Comment: i just opened the wikipedia link to the movie. The reference link is there itself, marked rules available here :)

Comment: Oh. Well, I missed it although it was there for me to see then. Thanks. And no, I won't play it IRL. I doubt I can find enough people who'd even consider playing the board game.

Comment: A game like this, would give Death Race a run for its money on pay per view :D

Comment: That version of the rules is pretty incomplete and leaves a lot to the imagination. There's a more complete version, transcribed from an interview? at this link, though it also completely omits the showdown, for example. https://seedyroad.com/diversions/quintet.htm#:~:text=118%20mins-,quintet%3A%20the%20game,-The%20game%20of